# MySQL connection error in VB.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to connect my vb.net webform to a MySQL database but get the following error on running:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

This is my code:

```
        Dim Sqlconnection As New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=orderadmin;password=***;database=pfrorder")
        Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM orders"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Sqlconnection.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Sqlconnection.Close()
```

Comment: How are you associating Sqlconnection  with sqladapter, cmd , and reader ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A command, an adapter or a reader to accomplish their tasks need to use an open connection. You have opened a connection, but you don't have it associated to your MySqlCommand. so when you call ExecuteReader it doesn't know how to reach your db. To fix the problem, just use the MySqlCommand constructor that takes the sql text and the connection

```
Using connection = New MySqlConnection("...."=
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM orders", connection)
    connection.Open()
    Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        .... do you stuff reading values from the reader here ...
        .... if you close the connection, the reader is also closed ....
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Notice also that every disposable object like a connection, a command or a reader should always disposed when you don't need them anymore. The [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) ensures that your objects are closed and disposed also if you get an exception,

(I have also changed the name of the MySqlConnection variable to a less confusing name with the `Sql Server SqlConnection` class)